# A string.Format question (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone elaborate on the following format string? I don't completely realize the meaning.

```
String.Format("{0:#,0.##}", money);
```

Thanks.

Comment: see String Formatting in C#: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means that the money have thousand separator(,) and if in decimal values it will be rounded to two digits after decimal, and if there is only decimal values(.256) it will be (0.27)

```
decimal money=12341257    //output= 12,341,257 
decimal money=1257        //output= 1,257
decimal money=1257.25     //output= 1,257.25
decimal money=1257.2468   //output= 1,257.25
decimal money=.50         //output= 0.50
decimal money=.759        //output= 0.76
```

**Explanation:**

```
 "{0:#,0.##}"
  #,0  //means that , as thousand seperator
  0.## //means that 0 is placed before if only decimal values as .56 to 0.56
  0.## //means if contains decimal then only display 2 digits after decimal
  0.00 //means 2 digits after decimal must be displayed whether or not money contains decimal value
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have my development system with me so I can't verify what I'm about to say, but here's my interpretation:

The format portion is "#,0.##". I'm thinking the "#,0" portion specifies a comma should separate thousands (e.g. 1,000,000). And the ".##" is specifying the number of digits after the decimal. I would have thought you'd need ".00" to force two digits (which would be normal for currency). But I would expect what you have to at least cause rounding to two digits after the decimal.

Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a currency format with a thousands separator and showing only the first 2 places after the decimal if decimal values are included.

Good overview of custom format strings here:
http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

This link includes more details including a description of a more liberal form of the thousands separator with the "," char:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this set the formatting to have a thousands separator and 2 decimal digits. According to Microsoft documentation, numbers will be rounded to the correct decimal places.

This is a good resource for custom numeric format strings :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx